# ng-dblclick missing second doubleclick when done in rapid succession

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With ng-dblclick on Angular 1.4.3 when you click 4 times in rapid succession only 1 doubleclick is registered. Using this html:

```
<div ng-dblclick="incClicks();">Double Click Me!</div>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2SM2Htxsr9H7dHUBop1C?p=preview) to try it.

Tested in In Firefox 39 and Chromium 43

How can I make every doubleclick count?

Comment: Think isn't possible when you click more than 2 times, ng-dblclick is call when you click two time and no more. Try to use ng-click and do something when (count/2)...

Comment: Just an FYI, your plunker works in FF 40 beta. This isn't the first time I've seen this kind of behavior (also happens in GWT, for instance). I would recommend trying what @Alexis suggested.